# Efficient numerical calculation of 2d data sets

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to calculate the fourier transform of a gaussian beam. Later I want to ad some modifications to the following example code. With the required stepsize of 1e-6 the calculation with 8 kernel takes 1244s on my workstation. The most consuming part is obviously the generation of uaperture. Has anyone ideas to improve the performance? Why does mathematica not create a packed list from my expression, when I'm having both real and complex values in it?

```
uin[gx_, gy_, z_] :=  Module[{w0 = L1[[1]], z0 = L1[[3]], w, R, \[Zeta], k},
w = w0 Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2];
R = z (1 + (z0/z)^2);
\[Zeta] = ArcTan[z/z0];
k = 2*Pi/193*^-9;
Developer`ToPackedArray[
  ParallelTable[
  w0/w Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/w^2] Exp[-I k/2/R (x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[-I k z*0 + 
  I \[Zeta]*0], {x, gx}, {y, gy}]
  ]  
]

AbsoluteTiming[ 
dx = 1*^-6;  
gx = Range[-8*^-3, 8*^-3, dx];
gy = gx;
d = 15*^-3;
uaperture = uin[gx, gy, d];
ufft = dx*dx* Fourier[uaperture];
uout = RotateRight[
Abs[ufft]*dx^2, {Floor[Length[gx]/2], Floor[Length[gx]/2]}];
]
```

Thanks in advance,

Johannes

Comment: Use `ToPackedArray[ 0. I + array ]` to force everything to be `Complex` before packing.  Then it will succeed in creating a packed array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but  `ToPackedArray[ ParallelTable[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/w^2]Exp[-I k/2/R (x^2 + y^2)/2], {x, gx}, {y, gy}]]]` is a packed array. Unfortunately `ParallelTable` first evaluates as unpacked array and that consumes plenty of memory and time. If I try `ParallelTable[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/w^2], {x, gx}, {y, gy}]]]` without the complex part the result is a packed array.

Comment: I didn't take a good look at the code, but I *suspect* that `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"` in `ParallelTable` *may* reduce memory usage that is due to unpacking.  But then it may not ... just and idea to try.

Comment: Thanks, seems to improve the speed and memory overhead at least at my pc at home with 2 kernels, but I'm sure it will also speed up the workstation. But it's astonishing that compared with the same code implemented in Matlab, Mathematica takes more than 20 longer to compute the same result.

Comment: For future questions you can also try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/  It has a more active Mathematica community, almost no question goes unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed it up by first vectorizing it (`uin2`), then compiling it (`uin3`):

```
In[1]:= L1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};

In[2]:= uin[gx_, gy_, z_] :=
 Module[{w0 = L1[[1]], z0 = L1[[3]], w, R, \[Zeta], k},
  w = w0 Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2];
  R = z (1 + (z0/z)^2);
  \[Zeta] = ArcTan[z/z0];
  k = 2*Pi/193*^-9;
  ParallelTable[
   w0/w Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/
      w^2] Exp[-I k/2/R (x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[-I k z*0 + 
      I \[Zeta]*0], {x, gx}, {y, gy}]
  ]

In[3]:= uin2[gx_, gy_, z_] :=
 Module[{w0 = L1[[1]], z0 = L1[[3]], w, R, \[Zeta], k, x, y},
  w = w0 Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2];
  R = z (1 + (z0/z)^2);
  \[Zeta] = ArcTan[z/z0];
  k = 2*Pi/193*^-9;
  {x, y} = Transpose[Outer[List, gx, gy], {3, 2, 1}];
  w0/w Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/
     w^2] Exp[-I k/2/R (x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[-I k z*0 + I \[Zeta]*0]
  ]

In[4]:= uin3 =
  Compile[{{gx, _Real, 1}, {gy, _Real, 1}, z},
   Module[{w0 = L1[[1]], z0 = L1[[3]], w, R, \[Zeta], k, x, y},
    w = w0 Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2];
    R = z (1 + (z0/z)^2);
    \[Zeta] = ArcTan[z/z0];
    k = 2*Pi/193*^-9;
    {x, y} = Transpose[Outer[List, gx, gy], {3, 2, 1}];
    w0/w Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/
       w^2] Exp[-I k/2/R (x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[-I k z*0 + I \[Zeta]*0]
    ],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
   ];

In[5]:= dx = 1*^-5;
gx = Range[-8*^-3, 8*^-3, dx];
gy = gx;
d = 15*^-3;

In[9]:= r1 = uin[gx, gy, d]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[9]= {67.9448862, Null}

In[10]:= r2 = uin2[gx, gy, d]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[10]= {28.3326206, Null}

In[11]:= r3 = uin3[gx, gy, d]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[11]= {0.4190239, Null}
```

We got a ~160x speedup even though this is not running in parallel.

Results are the same:

```
In[12]:= r1 == r2
Out[12]= True
```

There's a tiny difference here due to numerical errors:

```
In[13]:= r2 == r3
Out[13]= False

In[14]:= Max@Abs[r2 - r3]
Out[14]= 5.63627*10^-14
```

Comment: Wow remarkable speedup! I know vectorizing code from using Matlab, but never used it that way in Mathematica. I'm also surprised from compiling the code. Many thanks for the example code and also for the mathematica.stackexchange.com link.